# CSS / HTML Using a counter to set a colour

Tags: html, css, colors, navigation, counter

I've decided to learn a bit of CSS / HTML

I'm making a navigation bar following roughly [this](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu) tutorial.
I like how the child links are a different colour from his tab parent links. I want to go a little further by making instead of all top links being white and child links being blue to each child list being progressively darker than its parent from white to black.

first of I tried using nth-child to do this but abandoned that method after discovering you couldn't use n as a value only an argument.

Now I'm trying to use counter to decrease before every child from white(255,255,255) to black. Decreasing the counters is not a problem but assigning the counters to the background colours does nothing,( where background-color: rgb(0,0,0,) would )

```
background-color: rgb(content: counter(Counter_Red),content: counter(Counter_Green),content: counter(Counter_Blue));
```

This is the piece of code which does not work. 
Is they any way to get it to work or alternet methods?

Comment: Have you tried `>` for selecting direct children not grand-children ? You can try `ul > li { color:black; } ul > li > ul > li { color:white; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add a `background-image` `linear-gradient` to the `ul`s:

```
ul {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(250,250,250) 91%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(250,250,250) 91%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(250,250,250) 91%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(250,250,250) 91%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(250,250,250) 91%);;
}
```

Here's a very simple [js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/k5jSA/) to illustrate.

[MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

[Simple gradient generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/)

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for.
Is they any way to make the gradient solid for each links' box, ie:

box 1- solid white,
box 2-solid light grey,
box 3-solid grey,
ect...-solid black

instead of pixel by pixel difference

Answer (score 0):

Try

CSS

```
nav ul li a {
color:#000;
    background:#FFF;
}
nav ul ul li a {
color:#000;
    background:#FFF;
}
```

Also you can use multi-level jquery menu available at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_multi_level_css_menu_horizontal_blue/